# Using Data Studio to display the column with the most inputs

Tags: looker-studio

I am making a Data Studio drawing from a very simple GSheet. I want to create a function that will display the name of the column with the most inputs. The columns represent different errors, and knowing which column has the most inputs will let me know which errors are most prevalent.

How could I do this?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: [As of REVISION 1] **Needs details**: Could you provide a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (TO-DO) (and sample data set(s) / Google Sheet (TO-DO)) of the scenario, that shows 1) Input table(s) (~9 rows) (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO)) 2) Expected output (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO)) 3) An attempt at solving the issue (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO))? Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion to a specific use case

Answer (score 0):

Create a **table**

*Dimension* = All the columns that represent different error

*Metric* = *Record Counts*

Sort by *Record Counts* descending order.

The first row is the column that has the most inputs.